# counting clock rising edges then produce a specific signal with FSM in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

sorry for my weak english .
I want to write a VHDL code of simple Control unit or TPG controller that produce a signal like S2 , that motivated from FSM which count two rising edge of clock and then make the s2=1, so I want help to write a code wich count two rise edge then produce s2=1. then in third cycle make it zero.

here is my code that does not work :

```
LIBRARY ieee ;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all ;
ENTITY TPG_CONTROL IS
    PORT (   Clock  : IN            STD_LOGIC ;
    TPG_CONTROL_En  : IN            STD_LOGIC ;
    --reset : IN            STD_LOGIC ;
        ST2             : OUT   STD_LOGIC ) ;
END TPG_CONTROL ;

ARCHITECTURE behav OF TPG_CONTROL IS
    SIGNAL Count : std_logic_vector(1 DOWNTO 0) := "00" ;

    TYPE state IS (S0, S1, S2);
SIGNAL Moore_state: state;
SIGNAL Clear: std_logic  ;
begin
U_Moore0: PROCESS (clock, Clear, TPG_CONTROL_En, Count)
BEGIN
    IF(Count = "11") THEN
        Moore_state <= S0;
        Clear <= '1';
    ELSIF ( (rising_edge (clock)) AND TPG_CONTROL_En= '1') THEN 
     -- IF (Count = "11") THEN Clear <= '1' THEN
            IF Clear = '1' THEN
                Count <= "00" ;
            ELSE
                Count <= Count + 1 ;
        --  END IF ;
--  END IF;
--  END IF;  
--  END IF;  

        CASE Moore_state IS
            WHEN S0 =>
              IF Count = "01" THEN
                    Moore_state <= S1; 
               -- ELSE
                 --  Moore_state <= S0;
                END IF;
WHEN S1 =>
              IF Count = "10" THEN 
                                     Moore_state <= S2; 
                           --   ELSE
                             --        Moore_state <= S1; 
                              END IF;
                      WHEN S2 =>
              IF Count = "11" THEN
                                     Moore_state <= S0; 
                               --         ELSE 
                              --       Moore_state <= S1; 
                              END IF;
        END CASE;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    --ST2 <= ‘1’ WHEN Moore_state = S2 ELSE ‘0’;
 END PROCESS;
U_Moore1: PROCESS (clock, TPG_CONTROL_En)
BEGIN
  IF ( (rising_edge (clock)) AND TPG_CONTROL_En= '1') THEN
    IF ( Moore_state = S2 ) THEN ST2 <= '1' ; 
    ELSE ST2 <= '0' ;
      END IF;
      END IF;

END PROCESS;
END behav ;
```

Comment: Can you describe what the code *does* do that is incorrect?  Also, tidy up your code, remove all the commented out lines and indent it clearly and uniformly.  Everything you can do to make the reader's life easier will make it more likely you will get an answer.

Comment: The comment `--ST2 <= '1' WHEN Moore_state = S2 ELSE '0';` uses back tick single quotes, which are illegal even in a comment.  Correcting those the design description analyzes and elaborates.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the back ticks in you're comment:

Was:
        --ST2 <= ‘1’ WHEN Moore_state = S2 ELSE ‘0’;
Is:
        -- st2 <= '1' when moore_state = s2 else '0';

Your code analyzes and elaborates.

Writing a simple testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tpg_control_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of tpg_control_tb is

    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal enab:    std_logic := '1';
    signal st2:     std_logic;

begin

CLOCK:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 100 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
DUT:
    entity work.tpg_control
    port map (   
        clock => clk,
        tpg_control_en => enab,
        st2 => st2
    );

end architecture;
```

with a constant tpg_control_en emonstrates the behavior to which you allude, that you aren't reaching S2.

If you comment out the asynchronous clear of moore_state by count:

```
u_moore0: process (clock, clear, tpg_control_en, count)
begin
    if(count = "11") then
        -- moore_state <= s0;
        clear <= '1';
    elsif ( (rising_edge (clock)) and tpg_control_en= '1') then 
     -- if (count = "11") then clear <= '1' then
            if clear = '1' then
                count <= "00" ;
            else
                count <= count + 1 ;
        --  end if ;
--  end if;
--  end if;  
--  end if;  

        case moore_state is
            when s0 =>
              if count = "01" then
                    moore_state <= s1; 
               -- else
                 --  moore_state <= s0;
                end if;
when s1 =>
              if count = "10" then 
                                     moore_state <= s2; 
                           --   else
                             --        moore_state <= s1; 
                              end if;
                      when s2 =>
              if count = "11" then
                                     moore_state <= s0; 
                               --         else 
                              --       moore_state <= s1; 
                              end if;
        end case;
    end if;
    end if;
    -- st2 <= '1' when moore_state = s2 else '0';
 end process;
```

You actually get there:

[image: tpg_control_tb]

I'd suspect without knowing why you have an asynchronous clear that the process statement sensitivity list could be reduced to `clock`.

And because unsigned/std_logic_vector "+" rolls over you can simply the heck out of what you have:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity tpg_control is
    port ( 
        clock:          in  std_logic;
        tpg_control_en: in  std_logic;
        --reset:        in  std_logic;
        st2:            out std_logic
    );
end tpg_control;

architecture behav of tpg_control is

    signal count : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "00" ;

    type state is (s0, s1, s2);
    signal moore_state: state;
    -- signal clear: std_logic;

begin

u_moore0: 
    process (clock)
    begin
        -- if(count = "11") then
            -- moore_state <= s0;
            -- clear <= '1';
        -- elsif ...
        if rising_edge(clock) and tpg_control_en = '1' then 

             -- if clear = '1' then
             --     count <= "00" ;
             -- else
            count <= count + 1;

            case moore_state is
                when s0 =>
                    if count = "01" then
                        moore_state <= s1; 
                    end if;
                when s1 =>
                    if count = "10" then 
                        moore_state <= s2; 
                    end if;
                when s2 =>
                    if count = "11" then
                        moore_state <= s0; 
                    end if;
             end case;
             -- end if;
        end if;
     end process;

u_moore1: 
    process (clock)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) and tpg_control_en = '1' then
            if  moore_state = s2 then 
                st2 <= '1' ; 
            else st2 <= '0' ;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end behav ;
```

And this shows the state roll over:

[image: no clear]

Note that count and moore_state hold the same information in two different type formats.  You don't actually need both.  Generally synthesis tools would be capable of producing a working implementation from moore_state alone.